# apex:inputFile - cannot be used with ---- that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting below error on my visualforce page.How to solve this?

apex:inputFile - cannot be used with ---- that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute

please find my code below

```
<apex:page standardController="ENT_ED_LIHTC__c" extensions="TstDocHub_LIHTCDeal_Checklist_Controller" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" action="{!FillNode}">
    <head>
        <script>
            function removeLine(Id)
            {
                var a = confirm('Do you really want to remove this section? If the answer is "Yes" then click "OK"');
                if(a)
                {
                    document.getElementById(Id).style.display='inline';
                    removeSec(Id);
                }
                else 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            function removeSingleLine(Id,Str)
            {
                var a = confirm('Do you really want to remove this document? If the answer is "Yes" then click "OK"');
                if(a)
                {
                    document.getElementById(Str).style.display='inline';
                    removeDc(Id,Str);
                }
                else 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <style>

    </style>
    <!--<ul id="tree">
        <apex:repeat value="{!Nodes}" var="mainnode">
            <li><strong><apex:outputtext style="color:blue;" escape="false" value="{!mainnode.Parent}"/></strong>
            <ul>
                <apex:repeat value="{!mainnode.Child}" var="mm">
            <li><span><apex:outputtext style="color:green;" escape="false" value="{!mm['Subtype__c']}"/></span></li>
        </apex:repeat>
            </ul>
            </li>
                </apex:repeat>
    </ul>-->
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!FillNode}" name="Fill" status="stat" reRender="spanel"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="removeSec" action="{!RemoveSection}" status="stat1" reRender="spanel" oncomplete="javascript:window.location.reload()">
            <apex:param name="sec" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:actionFunction name="removeDc" action="{!RemoveDoc}" status="stat1" reRender="spanel" oncomplete="javascript:window.location.reload()">
            <apex:param name="DocName" value="" />
            <apex:param name="typeName" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <!--<apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!EditNA}" reRender="spanel" status="stat" rendered="{!showButton}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" reRender="spanel"   action="{!NADocs}" status="stat" rendered="{!showButton}"/>-->
                <input type="button" value="Checklist Report" class="btn" onclick="window.open('/00Oa0000007eDkE?pv0={!TempProject.Name}&pv1={!TempProject.Id}','_blank')" />
                <apex:actionStatus id="stat">
                <apex:facet name="start">
                    <img src="/img/loading24.gif"/>
                </apex:facet>
                </apex:actionStatus>
                <!-- <input type="button" value="Print As Pdf" class="btn" onclick="window.open('https://enterprise--content--c.cs1.visual.force.com/apex/PrintableVersion?id={!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}','bla','width=800,height=600,menubar=1,toolbar=1');"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Print as PDF" id="targetName" onclick="javascript:windows.location('www.google.com');" />-->
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:outputPanel id="spanel">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!Nodes}" var="nn" >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Edit All" action="{!EditNA}"  status="stat" rendered="{!showButton}"/>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save All"   action="{!NADocs}" status="stat" rendered="{!showButton}"/>
                       <apex:pageblockSection title="{!nn.Parent}" showHeader="{!IF(nn.Parent=='',false,true)}" columns="1" id="node" collapsible="false">

                            <!-- <apex:repeat value="{!nn.Child}" var="cc">-->
                            <apex:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="3">
                                <apex:panelGroup >
                                    <div style="margin-top:5px;">
                                    <apex:outputText value="{!nn.TChild}" escape="false" style="font-weight:bold; height:30px"/>
                                    </div>
                                </apex:panelGroup>
                                <!--<apex:actionStatus id="stat1">
                                <apex:facet name="start"></apex:facet>
                                <apex:facet name="stop">-->
                                <input type="button" class="btn"   value="Remove"  onclick="removeLine('{!nn.TChild}')"   style="display:{!IF(AND(nn.TChild!=null,showButton==true),'inline;','none;')}"/>
                                <img src="/img/loading24.gif" id="{!nn.TChild}" style="display:none;"/>
                            </apex:panelGrid>
                            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!nn.DocType2}" var="dt">
                                     <apex:column >                                      
                                          <apex:commandLink Value="Edit" action="{!allowEdit}" style="font-weight:bold"  status="stat" rendered="{!IF(dt.isEditMode==true,false,true)}">             
                                                <apex:param name="param2" value="{!dt.itemProject.Id}" assignTo="{!editRecordId}"/>
                                         </apex:commandLink>

                                         <apex:commandLink Value="Save" action="{!saveRecord}" style="font-weight:bold"  status="stat" rendered="{!IF(dt.isEditMode==true,true,false)}" >
                                               <apex:param name="param3" value="{!dt.itemProject.Id}" assignTo="{!editRecordId}"/>
                                         </apex:commandLink> 
                                         {!message}
                                     </apex:column>
                                    <apex:column headerValue="Uploaded" >
                                        <apex:Image value="{!IF((dt.itemProject.Uploaded_Project_Documents1__r.size>0 || dt.na==true) ,$Resource.Uploaded,$Resource.Notuploaded)}"/>
                                    </apex:column>
                                    <apex:column headerValue="N/A Status">
                                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!dt.na}" id="na" 
                                        disabled="{!IF(DisplayNA==true || dt.isEditMode==true,false,true)}"                             
                                        onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById(this.name.replace('na','pc')).checked = false;}" />
                                    </apex:column>
                                    <apex:column headerValue="PC">
                                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!dt.pc}" id="pc"
                                        disabled="{!IF(DisplayNA==true || dt.isEditMode==true,false,true)}" 
                                        onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById(this.name.replace('pc','na')).checked = false;}" />
                                    </apex:column> 
                                    <apex:column value="{!dt.itemProject.Type_Number__c}"/>
                                    <apex:column value="{!dt.itemProject.Name}"/>
                                    <apex:column headerValue="Upload Document">

                                      <!--<apex:inputFile title="Choose a file up to 10MB" id="file" value="{!FileBody}" fileName="{!filename}"  tabindex="1"/>
                                        -->                                          
                                         <apex:inputFile title="Choose a file up to 10MB"  value="{!dt.cl.FileBody}"  disabled="{!IF(DisplayNA==true || dt.isEditMode==true,false,true)}" fileName="{!dt.cl.ContentToUpload.PathOnClient}" tabindex="1"/>
                                    </apex:column>                                
                                    <apex:column headerValue="Document Link">
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!dt.itemProject.Uploaded_Project_Documents1__r}" var="cc">
                                        <br>
                                        <!--<a target="_blank" href="/{!cc.Content_Id__c}">{!cc.Title__c}</a></br>-->
                                        <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="/{!cc.Content_Id__c}" rendered="{!IF(cc.Content_Id__c != null,true,false)}">{!cc.Title__c}</apex:outputLink></br>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                        </apex:column>  

                                    <apex:column headerValue="Document Status">
                                        <apex:repeat value="{!dt.itemProject.Uploaded_Project_Documents1__r}" var="cc">
                                           <apex:outPutField value="{!cc.Status__c}" 
                                           rendered="{!IF((DisplayNA==false && dt.isEditMode==false) || cc.Status__c == 'Not Applicable' || cc.Status__c == 'Post Closing' ,true,false)}" /><br/>
                                           <apex:InPutField value="{!cc.Status__c}"  
                                           rendered="{!IF((DisplayNA==true || dt.isEditMode==true)&& cc.Status__c != 'Not Applicable' && cc.Status__c != 'Post Closing',true,false)}" />                                          
                                        </apex:repeat>                                      
                                    </apex:column>

                                    <apex:column headerValue="Comments">
                                        <apex:repeat value="{!dt.itemProject.Uploaded_Project_Documents1__r}" var="cc">
                                              <apex:outPutField value="{!cc.Comments__c}" 
                                              rendered="{!IF(DisplayNA==false && dt.isEditMode==false,true,false)}"/>
                                              <apex:InPutField value="{!cc.Comments__c}"  
                                              rendered="{!IF(DisplayNA==true || dt.isEditMode==true,true,false)}"/> 
                                        </apex:repeat>
                                    </apex:column>

                                    <apex:column >
                                        <apex:actionStatus id="stat2">
                                        <apex:facet name="start">
                                            <img src="/img/loading24.gif" />
                                        </apex:facet>
                                        <apex:facet name="stop">
                                            <!--<apex:commandButton status="stat2" reRender="spanel" value="Remove" rendered="{!IF(AND(nn.TChild==null,$Profile.Name=='System Administrator'),true,false)}" action="{!RemoveDoc}" oncomplete="javascript:window.top.location='/{!TempProject.id}'">
                                            <apex:param name="param2" value="{!dt.itemProject.Name}" assignTo="{!DocName}"/>
                                            <apex:param name="param1" value="{!nn.Parent}" assignTo="{!typeName}"/>
                                            </apex:commandButton>-->
                                        </apex:facet>
                                        </apex:actionStatus>
                                        <!--<input type="button" class="btn"   value="Remove"  onclick="removeSingleLine('{!dt.itemProject.Type_Number__c}','{!nn.Parent}')"   style="display:{!IF(AND(nn.TChild==null,showButton==true),'inline;','none;')}"/>-->
                                        <input type="button" class="btn"   value="Remove"  onclick="removeSingleLine('{!dt.itemProject.Type_Number__c}','{!nn.Parent}')" style="display:{!IF(AND(nn.TChild==null,showButton==true),'inline;','none;')}"/>
                                        <img src="/img/loading24.gif" id="{!nn.Parent}" style="display:none;"/>
                                    </apex:column>
                                </apex:pageblockTable>
                            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        </apex:pageblockSection>
                    </apex:repeat>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
        //window.setTimeout(Fill,1000);
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the VF markup including the `apex:inputFile` and `apex:command*` tags?

Comment: @MarkPond Updated with the code

Answer (score 11):

Can you post your VF code, so that someone here can tweak your code/ help you out?

There is a small trick that made my inputfile and commandbutton work flawless

I wrapped the command button in a actionregion something like this should work for you.

```
<apex:page controller="some_controller" sidebar="false" showheader="false">
<apex:pagemessages />
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:outputPanel >
<apex:inputFile value="{!file}" filename="{!file_name}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageblockbuttons location="bottom">
```

> ```
> <apex:actionRegion >
> <apex:commandbutton action="{!go}" value="Attach file" oncomplete="open_popup();">
> </apex:commandbutton>
> </apex:actionRegion>
> ```

```
<apex:commandbutton value="close" onclick="window.top.close();" />
</apex:pageblockbuttons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Updated with vf page

Comment: Wrapping the <apex:commandButton> is the way to go.  It's worked for me :)

Comment: @amatorVitae happy that it worked :)

Comment: @ rao ..current view state of my page is 87 kb..page is very huge

Comment: yes.. when i try to upload document ..i am getting view state error

Comment: Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded. Actual view state size for this page was 245.062KB

Comment: @Kiran please refrain from changing the scope of the question completely and reedit the post to the original question. Start a new question about the view state. My answer looks like it makes no sense to someone who will visit this site after your issue is solved.

Comment: @rao sure i will start new question

Comment: @kiran can you please reedit and have the original title so that other users who follow will find the question and answer relevant

Comment: @Rao.. I have been trying the above code. the error is gone but unfortunately, the attachment body is always null in the controller. Do you see any reason ?

Comment: @AmitBangad  open this as a new question and post your controller logic, the attachment part happens in the controller and has nothing to do with the page

Answer (score -3):

For clearing the view state, after inserting the document at finally block clear the body, which will clear the viewstate.

```
try {    
      insert document;    
    } catch (DMLException e) {

    } finally {

      document.body = null; // clears the viewstate
      document = new Document();

    }
```

I hope the above code which may help you. I'm also new to salesforce. correct me if wrong.

Regards,
Arun