# problem with uploading document .. missing fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, upload, document

I have a page with uploading document form, I followed this [example](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/uploading-a-document-using-visualforce-and-a-custom-controller) but I got a problem when I try to upload the file with the following error message `Required fields are missing: [Document Name]`

And here is my VF code

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Scan Document" >
  <apex:form id="scanDocumentTabForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
                  <apex:inputText value="{!document.name}"
                                  id="fileName"/>
                  <apex:inputFile value="{!document.body}"
                                  filename="{!document.name}"
                                  id="file"/>
                  <apex:inputField label="Description" value="{!document.description}"/>
                  <apex:actionRegion >
                       <apex:commandButton value="Upload File"
                                           action="{!saveDocument}"
                                           reRender="documentsTableForm"
                                           status="getDoc"/>
                  </apex:actionRegion>

            </apex:PageBlockSection>

            <apex:actionStatus startStyleClass="loading"
                               stopStyleClass="unload"
                               id="getDoc"/>

            <apex:pageMessages /> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                  <apex:panelGroup id="documentsTable">
                        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!documents}" var="doc" >
                             // table content .. 
                                    <!-- This is the dynamic reference part -->                    
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                  </apex:panelGroup>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

And this is the Controller Code

```
public Document document {get; set;}

public MyController (){
        document = new Document();
}

public pageReference saveDocument() {

        document.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        document.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();

        try {
            insert document;

        } catch (DMLException e) {        
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading file'));

        return null;
        } finally {
          document.body = null; // clears the viewstate
          document = new Document();
        }

        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'File uploaded successfully'));

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using action riegon?

Comment: Because I'm using commandLink with reRender, so I got error "Conjunction" in fileInput, Solved it with ActionRiegon from this source http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16837/apexinputfile-cant-be-used-in-conjunction-with-an-action-component-when-im-tr

Comment: Error : apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-render don't work with `<apex:input>` but there is is no problem in page reload. On page refresh no information lost and data changes during action method call these details can be used on page

Here is an example using above sample code:

```
    public class DocumentUploader {
    public Document document {get; set;}
    public List<document> documents {get; set;}

    public DocumentUploader (){
            document = new Document();
            // Will show 3 results
            documents = [SELECT id, name, description FROM Document LIMIT 3];
    }

    public pageReference saveDocument() {

            document.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            document.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();

            try {
                insert document;

            } catch (DMLException e) {        
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading file'));

            return null;
            } finally {
              document.body = null; // clears the viewstate
              document = new Document();
              // This will load all document and refresh page. Constructor not reloads
              documents = [SELECT id, name, description FROM Document];
            }

            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'File uploaded successfully'));

            PageReference pref = ApexPages.currentPage();
            pref.setRedirect(false);
            return pref;
        }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="DocumentUploader" tabstyle="Document">
<apex:form>
 <apex:pageblock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
         <apex:pagemessages/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!document.name}" id="fileName"/>
         <apex:inputFile value="{!document.body}" filename="{!document.name}" id="file"/>
         <apex:inputField label="Description" value="{!document.description}"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="Upload File" action="{!saveDocument}" status="getDoc" />
    </apex:PageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!documents}" var="doc">
      <apex:column value="{!doc.name}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!doc.description}"/>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
  </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Ok, but I have tabs and when the page refresh.. it's return to the first tab.

Comment: @user3003810 updated my answer. You can set `tabstyle="document"` in apex page as attribute

Comment: the same thing, I'll try to make selectedTab attribute for tabPanel dynamic, it may help .. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your saveDocument() method, before insert query, try

```
document.Name = 'ANY NAME OF YOUR CHOICE';
```

It should work.

**UPDATE:**

```
<apex:inputFile value="{!document.body}" filename="{!document.name}" id="file"/>
<apex:ActionRegion>
<apex:inputField value="{!document.name}" id="fileName"/>
<apex:inputField label="Description" value="{!document.description}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Upload File"
                                       action="{!saveDocument}"
                                       reRender="documentsTableForm"
                                       status="getDoc"/>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Comment: Ok, It should work and works fine I tried it. but the document was saved without description, this means .. the form fields not work !

Comment: Great! Can you put a debug statement in your constructor and see if it is getting called when you click on Upload File. It it is the case, try creating a getter method for document = new Document(); instead of putting that in constructor.

Comment: I removed actionRegion , and the reRender attribute .. and it works fine but it is refreshing the whole page !

Comment: Try to enclose actionRegion around the fields you have on form. When you put ActionRegion only the components inside it, will we processed by server.

Comment: Visualforce Error

apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute.

Comment: Keep Apex:inputFile outside the apexRegion.... Just shuffle your fields a bit, so that apex:inputFile is outside actioRegion and other fields are inside actionRegion.

Comment: All fields inside the Region inserted except the document it self ! I tried to upload a .txt file but the result was.. File Extension Unknown, Size 0 bytes.

Comment: Looks like we are hitting a wall here. 
Check this out as a last resort, see post by erai yoshinaga, I have not validated that so you might to check the validity of that code: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000096MRIAY

Comment: Thank you very much for your trying to help, this problem will make me crazy !