# apex:selectList isn't working with apex:actionRegion

Tags: visualforce, selectoption, actionregion

I am building a Single App Application and got this error on a vf page:

> apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute.

I followed the chosen answer on this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/16958/38518) by sfdcfox and added `apex:actionRegion` but, it created a different problem.
It seems that the `apex:selectList` isn't working if it's nested in `apex:actionRegion`. When I choose one of the options on the drop-down, I expect it to change the page (i.e. display another section of the page since it's SPA) but nothing happens and no errors, the debug log status shows success.

Please advise

VF Snippet:

```
<apex:form id="formId">
    <apex:pageBlock title="" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageMessage summary="{!$Label.Read_only_mode_message}" severity="info" strength="2" rendered="{!DRD_Submited}" />
        <apex:pageMessages escape="false" />
        <apex:pageBlockButtons title="">
            <apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:selectList value="{!pageNumber}" size="1>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!changePage}" rerender="formId" />
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!pageList}" />
                </apex:selectList>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" rendered="{!sm.currentVisibleStep < sm.StepMaxVisible}" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!previous}" value="Previous" rendered="{!sm.currentVisibleStep > 1}" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!next}" value="Save and Continue" rendered="{!sm.currentVisibleStep < sm.StepMaxVisible && !DRD_Submited}" />
            </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public Integer pageNumber {get; set;}

public void changePage() {
    save();
    sm.currentStep = pageNumber;
}

public List < SelectOption > getPageList() {
    List < SelectOption > options = new List < SelectOption > ();
    options.add(new SelectOption('', '-- Choose Page --'));
    for (integer i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        options.add(new SelectOption('' + i, '' + i));
    }
    return options;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <apex:page controller="TestChildClass">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

    <script>
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    function storeFileData(){
        var fileData = j$( "#fileInput" ).attr( "files")[ 0 ];
        console.log( fileData );
        // do some javascript work with your files here  ...
    }
    </script>
   <apex:form id="formId">

    <apex:pageBlock title="" mode="edit">
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!changePage}" name="changePage" rerender="formId"/>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" /><button onclick="storeFileData()">Save File</button><br />
        Current Step: {!sm.CurrentStep}<br />
        <apex:selectList value="{!pageNumber}"
                         size="1"
                         onchange="changePage();">
             <apex:selectOptions value="{!pageList}" />
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:actionRegion id="section2">

         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 1" rendered="{!pageNumber = '1'}">
             Section 1 Rendered
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 2" rendered="{!pageNumber = '2'}">
             Section 2 Rendered
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 3" rendered="{!pageNumber = '3'}">
             Section 3 Rendered
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 4" rendered="{!pageNumber = '4'}">
             Section 4 Rendered
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 5" rendered="{!pageNumber = '5'}">
             Section 5 Rendered
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 6" rendered="{!pageNumber = '6'}">
             Section 6 Rendered
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <!--<apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" rendered="{!sm.currentVisibleStep < sm.StepMaxVisible}" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!previous}" value="Previous" rendered="{!sm.currentVisibleStep > 1}" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!next}" value="Save and Continue" rendered="{!sm.currentVisibleStep < sm.StepMaxVisible && !DRD_Submited}" /> -->
        </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I've updated my solution to address the error that you were receiving - this will work with file inputs and will not error when rerendering form components

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately it didn't work. I got the same error.

Comment: Are you referencing the error for the inputFile error or the error with the operation of the select list, I notice you're listing two- but seemingly asking for help with the issue of the multi select. I can see for sure you would still get an error with the input file here. For that, Iwould say to store a blob variable in a hidden field and use JS on a standard HTML input type=file to pass a blob  to the controller .

Comment: HTML file input won't get that error when using action regions an you can then use the blob to work with creating your attachment on the back end. Or even store as string and pass the file as a string converted in JS to the backend. And on the backend, convert to blob for attachment

Comment: Referencing the inputFile error