# apex:inputFile Error actionRegion tag not resolving issue

Tags: apex, rerender, repeat, form, apexinputfile

Can some one please let me know why I am getting this error here?

```
<apex:page controller="abc">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="addRow" action="{!addRow}" reRender="container">
            <apex:param name="keyValue" assignTo="{!keyValue}" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <apex:pageBlock id="container">
            <apex:repeat value="{!attachmentMap}" var="key">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="section {!key}">
                    <apex:outputLabel>Section {!key}</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="btn" onclick="addRow('{!key}')">
                        <apex:outputLabel>Add</apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!attachmentMap[key]}" var="uploadFile">
                        <apex:inputFile value="{!uploadFile.body}" ></apex:inputFile>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Error:
apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [apex:inputFile - cannot be used with ---- that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16635/apexinputfile-cannot-be-used-with-that-specifies-a-rerender-or-oncomplet)

Comment: It is not getting resolved by <apex:actionRegion >  as suggested in the Q/A you are refering

Comment: Might also help to know exactly when you get the error. Did you get this error when you tried to add a row (which is likely the culprit)? Have you tried wrapping both the `inputFile` AND the `actionFunction` in `actionRegion`s. If so, please let us know what you have tried in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have got it done ! In my case putting the apex: actionfunction in another form tag outside resolved the issue.

    
        
            -->

```
        <apex:param id="key" name="keyValue" assignTo="{!keyValue}" value=""/>

    </apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="container">

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="section 1">
            <apex:outputLabel >Section 1</apex:outputLabel>
          <apex:actionRegion >
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="btn" onclick="addRow('1')">
                <apex:outputLabel >Add</apex:outputLabel>
            </apex:outputPanel>
          </apex:actionRegion>
            <apex:repeat value="{!attachmentMap['1']}" var="uploadFile">
                <apex:inputFile value="{!uploadFile.body}" fileName="{!uploadFile.name}" />
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:form>
```