# Attachments to a custom Object - DmlExecutionException

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

TestCompone.page

```
<apex:page standardController="WebformData__c" extensions="TestCompon">
<apex:form >
<apex:outputLabel >Pick One</apex:outputLabel><br/>
<apex:selectList id="po" value="{!svalue}" size="1" required="TRUE" multiselect="FALSE">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!otherOpt}"/>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!onChangeFnCall}" rerender="pg"/>
</apex:selectList>

<apex:outputPanel id="pg">
  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!pgRendered}">
    <div>
      <c:testcompo values="{!svalue}"/>
    </div>
  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

testcompo.component

```
 <apex:component controller="TestCompon" allowDML="true">
 <apex:attribute name="values" type="String" description="picklistvalue" required="TRUE" assignTo="{!plvalue}"/>
    <br/><br/>
<div>
      <apex:outputLabel value="file" for="file"/>
      <apex:inputFile value="{!file.body}" filename="{!file.name}" id="file"/>
  </div>
<apex:outputLabel escape="false" value="<b>Enter Data</b>" style="white-space: pre" for="sDataId"/>
<apex:inputtext style="width: 360px;" id="sDataId" value="{!sdata}"/><br/><br/><br/>

 <div class="center">
     <apex:commandButton styleClass="TabSpace" action="{!save}" value="Save" />
 </div>
</apex:component>
```

TestCompon class

```
public Class TestCompon{
  public boolean pgRendered {get;set;}
  public String svalue;
      public void setsvalue(String record) {
        svalue = record;
      }
      public String getsvalue() {
         return svalue;
      }
    public Attachment file {
    get {
        if (file == null)
          file = new Attachment();
        return file;
      }
    set;
    }
  public List<SelectOption> otherOpt;
  public String plvalue {get;set;}
  public String sdata {get;set;}


  public TestCompon() {
  }

 public TestCompon(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    otherOpt = new List<SelectOption>();
  }
  public List<SelectOption> getOtherOpt() {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult description = WebformData__c.otherOptions__c.getDescribe();
    for (Schema.Picklistentry pl : description.getPicklistValues())
   {
        otherOpt.add(new SelectOption(pl.getValue(),pl.getLabel()));
    }
    return otherOpt;
  }

  public void onChangeFnCall(){
     if(getsvalue()=='HPC'){
         pgRendered = TRUE;
         System.debug('svalue' + getsvalue());

     }
   }
     private WebformData__c buildForm(){
      WebformData__c form = new WebformData__c();
      form.Sensitive_Data__c = sData;
      return form;
    }
   public PageReference save(){
      WebformData__c form = buildForm();
      try{
       // code to save the attachment
        insert form;
        Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = form.Id, name=file.name, body = file.body);
        System.debug('attachment.name: ' + attachment.name);// Prints NULL
        System.debug('attachment.body: ' + attachment.body);// prints NULL

        insert a; // Exception occurs here since name and body are null why?
      }catch(Exception ex){
        system.debug(ex);
      }
      return null;
    }

}
```

Exception:

> ```
> 00:02:56:029 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT 
>   [60]|ex|"common.apex.runtime.impl.DmlExecutionException: Insert failed.
>   First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, 
>   Required fields are missing: [otherOptions]: [otherOptions]"|0x261632fd
> ```

Comment: I can't remember attachment have any field name "otherOptions". Do you have any trigger on them?

Comment: Does your object WebformData__c  have a field named `otherOptions`? If yes, add a value to that field in your buildForm method.

Comment: @N.B,  Yes WebformData__c has a field otherOptions. Error occurs inserting the attachment. attachment name and body prints null when I insert debuglogs

Comment: @Tushar Sharma, Please ignore Otheroptions, it is just a picklist value. I dont have triggers in this. I am stuck only at the attachments

Comment: You can not user input file and rerender functionality in VF pages, you always need to have a page reload to get file data in VF context -- for example https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16635/apexinputfile-cannot-be-used-with-that-specifies-a-rerender-or-oncomplet/16636#16636

Comment: You need to add a value for `otherOptions` before inserting `form`. As per the error `otherOptions` is a required field on object WebformData__c and since it is not filled, you are not able to insert `form` properly. Then you are using form.Id as `parentId` in Attachment, that's why it is failing.

Comment: Also, your debug statement is System.debug('attachment.name: ' + attachment.name);
while it should be `System.debug('attachment.name: ' + a.name);` . The newly created Attachment record is called `a`.

Comment: Thanks @N.B and Tushar Sharma,, I released my blunder mistakes
1) I have File variable on the top and created a new attachment and trying to insert it
2) I made other options filed while pasting the code here i forgot to remove it as a required field.
3) I pasted the wrong error. 

Thanks issue is RESOLVED

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.